# Understanding deepCopy concept

Tags: java, copy

I'm reading about the so called `UserType` in Hiberante that declares the `deepCopy(Object)` method. Authors suggest we use the following implementation for `immutable` classes:

> Because `MonetaryAmount` is an immutable class, the deepCopy() method
>   returns its argument.

Why? I thought the deepCopy implementing as follows:

```
public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value;
}
```

is actually a **shallow**-copy. What did I miss?

Comment: This is indeed a shallow copy.

Comment: It is both a shallow copy AND a deep copy ... given that the type is immutable.

Comment: @StephenC : You are right. I think then as per the API definition we should indeed call it a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable object's cannot change it's state. So it doesn't matter if you return the same object. Since no modification can be done to it anyway. So it actually acts like a `deepCopy` when there is **no copy** at all.

Let's take an example of `String`.

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = new String(s1);
String s3 = s1;
```

It doesn't matter what operation you perform on any of the variables, it's not going to affect the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you return the same object you put into a method, then that's not any copy at all, neither swallow nor deep. A shallow copy would be if you copied all the references in the given object to a new one. A deep copy is when you dereference everything and create copies of all the child, etc. objects of your original.

Example:

MyObject has a reference to a Calendar object.

**Shallow Copy** to "MyCopy":

MyCopy (a new object, not the same (==) as MyObject) gets a **reference** to the **same** Calendar object.

Problem: If I now modify the Calendar of "MyCopy", the Calendar of "MyObject" will change, too, because it is the same one.

**Deep Copy:**

MyCopy gets a **new** Calendar which is a complete (itself deep) **copy** of the MyObject Calendar.

Advantage: If I now modify the Calendar of MyCopy, nothing changes for the one of MyObject.

If you have an immutable object, there is no need to deep copy it, because you can simply use the same object everywhere - it cannot be modified (thus immutable), so that is perfectly safe - and fast.

see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Methods_of_copying)